# HTML marquees need to wait for other to complete before start a scroll

Tags: html, marquee

I have many marquee in my page, each in separate line, and have different text length

```
<marquee class="mq">this finishes first</marquee>
<marquee class="mq">this finishes last because it has a veryyyyyyyyyyyyyyy longggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg text in it</marquee>
<marquee class="mq">this finishes secondly after 1st one</marquee>
```

When any marquee finish it scroll because of short text, it re-runs immediately after complete. But my requirement is to make it to wait for other marquees to finish theirs and start at the same time for the next loop
How can I implement this?

```css
.mq {
  width: 600px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<marquee class="mq">this finishes first</marquee>
<marquee class="mq">this finishes last because it has a veryyyyyyyyyyyyyyy longggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg text in it</marquee>
<marquee class="mq">this finishes secondly after 1st one</marquee>
```

Answer (score 0):

I myself found my own solution for this by using css animation instead of using marquee

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="marquee">text 1</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="marquee">text 2</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="marquee">text 3</div>
</div>

.marquee {
    width: fit-content;
}
```

Firstly, class marquee set div's width is fit-content to get real width of each div

Then run a loop to find the maximum width of all marquee (maxwidth)

Then set all marquee div with an inline style width property is maximum value of all marquee

Now every div.marquee has the same width is maxwidth (current width is inline style, override the current width style from marquee class)

All the div.marquee would run inside their own container with fixed width